# How to force android layout to show two views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I have layout I want to organize. Here is it's code: (partial)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#d9d9d9"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showingXoutOfY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/XOutOfY"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/copyright"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the `ScrollView` to fill the screen,BUT I want it to leave space for the `LinearLayout` with the `TextViews` in the bottom. As you can see I tried wrapping them inside a `RelativeLayout` and I aligned the `ScrollView` to the top and the `LinearLayout` to the bottom, but still it shows only the `ScrollView`.
The `TableLayout` which is nested in the `ScrollView` is populated dynamically.

Comment: So you want to display scrollview above TextView inside LinearLayout. Isn't it ?

Comment: @shree202 Yes. The container doesn't matter. Maybe it will be more clear if I tell what I want to do. the TableLayout is a list of items. the TextView contains information of how many items there are in the list

Comment: try setting scrollview's height as wrap content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

**android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout1"**

```
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d9d9d9"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showingXoutOfY"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/XOutOfY"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/copyright"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Check the line in bold, that parameter says it should always be above specified view

Comment: Did it, and eclipse says:
Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: I have edited the answer, it was due to linearlayout saying it should be below scroll view and scrollview saying it should be above linearlayout. Removed linearlayout saying below @scrollview

Comment: It did the trick. I can't mark the answer as accepted because I don't know which one of you ansewred first, so I marked the comment as useful...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#d9d9d9"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showingXoutOfY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/XOutOfY"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/copyright"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just add layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout1" in scrollview

Comment: Did it, and eclipse says: Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: Did this solve your problem ?? And also you can remove `layout_below` property from LinearLayout as it is no needed.

Comment: It did the trick. I can't mark the answer as accepted because I don't know which one of you ansewred first, so I marked the comment as useful...

Comment: No problem friend. You can accept any of the answer, i won't mind. Feel happy to help people here with whatever i know, i've learnt from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marginBottom attribute for ScrollView. Or use LinearLayout as parent and layout weight attribute to stretch scrollview